# Excel vba sumproduct with multiple criteria

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to sum values in a column extracted from an array and use two criteria to filter values. The formula returns a type mismatch error and I don't know why. Looking at the arrays in the watch window doesn't show up any obvious errors. Any suggestions?

```
    Sub TST_SUM_PROD()

    Dim VAL As Variant, DATA As Variant, ARR_PARAM As Variant, ARR_DEAL As Variant, ARR_STRAT As Variant


Set RNGE = Worksheets("BOOK").Range("tbl_BOOK").CurrentRegion
Set ARR_PARAM = RNGE.Columns(PARAM_COL)
Set ARR_DEAL = RNGE.Columns(DEAL_COL)
Set ARR_STRAT = RNGE.Columns(STRAT_COL)

SUM_IFS = Application.WorksheetFunction.SumIfs(ARR_PARAM, ARR_DEAL, DEAL_NO)`
    VAL = Application.WorksheetFunction.SumProduct(--(ARR_STRAT = "CAL"))
    VAL = Application.WorksheetFunction.SumProduct(--(ARR_DEAL = 1))
    VAL = Application.WorksheetFunction.SumProduct(ARR_PARAM, --(ARR_STRAT = "CAL"), --(ARR_DEAL = "1"))

End Sub
```

[image: SUMPRODUCT DATA]

Comment: check what result you have for this items: `--(ARR_STRAT = "CAL"),` and `--(ARR_DEAL = "1")`. Is it correct? What should it mean in your opinion?

Comment: I get a type mismatch error for both criteria `VAL = Application.WorksheetFunction.SumProduct(--(ARR_STRAT = "CAL"))` and `VAL = Application.WorksheetFunction.SumProduct(--(ARR_DEAL = "1"))` but there are no funny variables in the arrays except a few blanks

Comment: You can't compare an array to a single value using = in VBA, nor can you use `--` to coerce it to numbers. You'll have to use `Evaluate` and pass a formula string. (unless your criteria are actually contained in cells)

Comment: the criteria STRAT and DEAL_NO are values in two separate columns...so if I understand you correctly they are contained in cells. CAL is one of the cell values (there are others)

Comment: If you want the `True/False` or `0/1` values for the equality comparison, you will have to iterate the arrays item by item and build the array (or change existing values).  If you are going to do that, you may as well just do the sum in the loop in as well.  Ultimately, you cannot mix Excel formula notation with VBA formula notation.  I believe the point by @Rory, is that you can use `Application.Evaluate` in VBA to return a result from the Excel version of the formula, using normal ranges instead of the arrays like you're trying.

Comment: Thanks Rory and Byron. I did some more research and `sumproduct` and `sumifs` both usually use ranges, although `sumproduct` can use "built arrays".  Its a pity as I thought my code was fairly concise and easy to understand - I have been using loops and this was an attempt to improve the code. Do you know if extracting a range from a ws is significantly slower than building a 1xn array from larger mxn array?

Comment: STRAT and DEAL_NO are ranges, not the criteria, which are "CAL" and "1" in this case. If those values were in cells, you could do a one-liner using `WorksheetFunction.Countif` but otherwise you can use `Evaluate` and pass the same formula you'd use in a cell. Loading a range into an array is pretty quick as long as you don't have to loop cell by cell.

Comment: Thanks Rory. I used ranges and the `sumif` formula. The code works well and it easily fast enough.